# How to get Salesforce Lead object details in lambda Function?

Tags: lightning, leads, cti, amazon-connect-salesforce-cti

I have integrated my Salesforce instance with my AWS Connect through CTI Adapter. I also have implemented SalesforceLambda, which allows me to lookup Salesforce data.

**For Account**

I can get the Contact's country field using following event:

```json
    {
      "Details": {
        "Parameters": {
          "sf_operation": "phoneLookup",
          "sf_phone": "+31950785473",
          "sf_fields": "Country"
        }
      }
    }
```

**For Account**

To get data from Salesforce's Account I can use the following event:

```json
    {
      "Details": {
        "Parameters": {
          "sf_operation": "phoneLookup",
          "sf_phone": "+31950785473",
          "sf_fields": "account.City_CB__c"
        }
      }
    }
```

**My Problem**

**For Lead**

Now I want to get the value of Lead in my Lambda function. How can I get it? What do I have to put in `sf_fields`?

Comment: Out of the box - Account or Contact only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Amazon Connect for Salesforce [docs](https://amazon-connect.github.io/amazon-connect-salesforce-cti/docs/classic/salesforce-lambdas/01-contact-flow-salesforce-lambdas/), the `phoneLookup` operation is supported for Contact and its related object only (Hence you see Account works fine because Contact object is related to the Account). Hence it wont work with Lead as designed.

Instead use a [Lookup operation](https://amazon-connect.github.io/amazon-connect-salesforce-cti/docs/classic/salesforce-lambdas/01-contact-flow-salesforce-lambdas/#salesforce-lookup) as [documented](https://amazon-connect.github.io/amazon-connect-salesforce-cti/docs/classic/salesforce-lambdas/01-contact-flow-salesforce-lambdas/) to query  for Lead data.

You can also use [queryOne](https://amazon-connect.github.io/amazon-connect-salesforce-cti/docs/classic/salesforce-lambdas/01-contact-flow-salesforce-lambdas/#salesforce-queryone) operation too.

Comment: Can you please provide me with a query example through which I can get CityPicklist field. I have implemented one query but that didn't work. The query is "SELECT CityPicklist FROM Lead WHERE Phone LIKE \'%number%\".  It returns an error that says "MALFORMED_QUERY".

Comment: What is CityPicklist? If it is custom object you need API name for it like CityPicklist__c

Comment: I do not have CTI set up to give you the exact JSON but you can validate the query in the devconsole.

Comment: Thanks Mohith for your help, I have found  that.